# How to get json data from REST api SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services, rest

How to get json data from REST api in SharePoint 2013 list?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating a bit on Roman's answer:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://thisRestServiceURL",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { 
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    },
```

This would work for JQuery sending/receiving JSON Data.

Comment: Add this code to SharePoint site via CEWP? Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Sure you can, but if you're unsure of how to use JQuery to pull SharePoint JSON Data start learning, good resources: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for JQuery ajax command and  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx for the SharePoint REST API overview.

Comment: ...one last thing, you'll probably find the Script Editor Web Part: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/05/20/how-to-use-script-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx easier.

Comment: Thank you, I added script via Script Editor but after saved it, I see simple code on the page, nothig else?

Comment: I'm presuming you've thought out your display mechanism, perhaps open a second question and show us the code you've written thus far?

Answer (score 3):

You should pass Accept header, for example:
"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"

Comment: Yes but can you give me more details?

Comment: Which type of object model do you use?